# bootstrap modal dialog appearing at side of page

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a modal dialog that appears when i click on a thumbnail. I have a js (grabbed from an online source) with a basic bootstrap grid layout.

The problem is that 50% of the popup seems to hang off the edge of the page. It seems to work hen i reduce the width of the page.

My code is as follows (nb; you dont need the js to see this)

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge, chrome=1">
        <title>site name</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <link rel="logo" href="img/logo.png">
        <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
             <h1 class="page-header">Thumbnail Gallery</h1>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#" data-image-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-title="This is my title" data-caption="Some lovely red flowers" data-image="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/car-image.jpg" data-target="#image-gallery">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/car-image.jpg" alt="Short alt text" />
                </a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="image-gallery" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>

                </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="image-gallery-title"></h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img id="image-gallery-image" class="img-responsive" src="" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="show-previous-image">Previous</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 text-justify" id="image-gallery-caption">This text will be overwritten by jQuery</div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button type="button" id="show-next-image" class="btn btn-default">Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following fiddle shows the modal working.

As with the previous answer you should look at the structure of your HTML.

https://jsfiddle.net/6zzrL8ow/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
             <h1 class="page-header">Thumbnail Gallery</h1>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#" data-image-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-title="This is my title" data-caption="Some lovely red flowers" data-image="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/car-image.jpg" data-target="#image-gallery">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/car-image.jpg" alt="Short alt text" />
                </a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="image-gallery" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>

                </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="image-gallery-title"></h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img id="image-gallery-image" class="img-responsive" src="" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="show-previous-image">Previous</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 text-justify" id="image-gallery-caption">This text will be overwritten by jQuery</div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button type="button" id="show-next-image" class="btn btn-default">Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no luck, i have updated the q with the entire html file

Comment: In the fiddle I couldn't replicate the functionality you showed. Was it only happening on large width screens? If so it would be the lack of container potentially affecting positioning when the col was floated left

Comment: As per your updated question. What's in main.css and main.js?

Answer (score 1):

Is the initial section within a row? if not, it should be. It seems that the modal section immediately follows the first section with *col-lg-4*. It could be offsetting the modal due to the 4 columns being reserved by the first section. Try wrapping that section in a row and leaving the modal section outside of it.

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h1 class="page-header">Thumbnail Gallery</h1>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#" data-image-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-title="This is my title" data-caption="Some lovely red flowers" data-image="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/car-image.jpg" data-target="#image-gallery">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/car-image.jpg" alt="Short alt text">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="modal fade" id="image-gallery" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="image-gallery-title"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <img id="image-gallery-image" class="img-responsive" src="">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="show-previous-image">Previous</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-8 text-justify" id="image-gallery-caption">
                        This text will be overwritten by jQuery
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <button type="button" id="show-next-image" class="btn btn-default">Next</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: No luck, trying to get it working on jfiddle but its not showing the modal box even

Comment: Can you share the fiddle?

Comment: Dang, it works in jfiddle but not in mine, see updated question for screenshot....http://jsfiddle.net/q3ow0tp0/1/

Comment: Try wrapping in a container div like shown in the answer below.

Comment: See benembery's answer. If this doesn't work be sure that there is no other erroneous html in your file on your site

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and found it had nothing to do with how my modal html was set up. In my case my _Layout.cshtml was not referencing the correct stylesheet from my bootswatch theme. Correcting my style sheet reference fixed the issue.

I needed to replace

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" />`

with

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap-cerulean.css" />`

(replacing bootrap-cerulean with your custom stylesheet)

It's probably too late to help your situation but hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was to remove the head ref below:

See below for a nice starting template for popup gallery with pictures on web (doesnt work for local pics, working that).

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge, chrome=1">
        <title>site name</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <link rel="logo" href="img/logo.png">
        <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">



        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
             <h1 class="page-header">Thumbnail Gallery</h1>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb"> <a class="thumbnail" href="#" data-image-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-title="This is my title" data-caption="Some lovely red flowers" data-image="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/car-image.jpg" data-target="#image-gallery">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/car-image.jpg" alt="Short alt text" />
                </a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="image-gallery" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>

                </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="image-gallery-title"></h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img id="image-gallery-image" class="img-responsive" src="" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="show-previous-image">Previous</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 text-justify" id="image-gallery-caption">This text will be overwritten by jQuery</div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button type="button" id="show-next-image" class="btn btn-default">Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```